# MapReduceIndexerTool output dir error "Cannot write parent of file"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I want to use Cloudera's MapReduceIndexerTool to understand how morphlines work. I created a basic morphline that just reads lines from the input file and I tried to run that tool using that command:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool \
    --morphline-file morphline.conf                                                                                  \
    --output-dir hdfs:///hostname/dir/                                          \
    --dry-run true
```

Hadoop is installed on the same machine where I run this command.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.ArgumentParserException: Cannot write parent of file: hdfs:/hostname/dir
at org.apache.solr.hadoop.PathArgumentType.verifyCanWriteParent(PathArgumentType.java:200)
```

The /dir directory has 777 permissions on it, so it is definitely allowed to write into it. I don't know what I should do to allow it to write into that output directory.

I'm new to HDFS and I don't know how I should approach this problem. Logs don't offer me any info about that.

What I tried until now (with no result):

- created a hierarchy of 2 directories (/dir/dir2) and put 777 permissions on both of them
- changed the output-dir schema from hdfs:///... to hdfs://... because all the examples in the --help menu are built that way, but this leads to an invalid schema error

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem after days of working on it.

The problem is with that line `--output-dir hdfs:///hostname/dir/`.

1. First of all, there are not 3 slashes at the beginning as I put in my continuous trying to make this work, there are only 2 (as in any valid HDFS URI). Actually I put 3 slashes because **otherwise, the tool throws an invalid schema exception!** You can easily see in [this](https://github.com/cloudera/search/blob/cdh5-1.0.0_5.2.0/search-mr/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/hadoop/PathArgumentType.java) code that the schema check is done *before* the *verifyCanWriteParent* check.
2. I tried to get the hostname by simply running the **hostname** command on the Cent OS machine that I was running the tool on. **This** was the main issue. I analyzed the /etc/hosts file and I saw that there are 2 hostnames for the same local IP. I took the second one and it worked. (I also attached the port to the hostname, so the final format is the following: `--output-dir hdfs://correct_hostname:8020/path/to/file/from/hdfs`
3. This error is **very confusing** because everywhere you look for the namenode hostname, you will see the same thing that the hostname command returns. Moreover, the errors are not structured in a way that you can diagnose the problem and take a logical path to solve it.

**Additional information regarding this tool and debugging it**

- If you want to see the actual code that runs behind it, check the cloudera version that you are running and select the same branch on [the official repository](https://github.com/cloudera/search). The master is not up to date.
- If you want to just run this tool to play with the morphline (by using the --dry-run option) without connecting to Solr and playing with it, you can't. You have to specify a Zookeeper endpoint and a Solr collection or a solr config directory, which involves additional work to research on. This is something that can be improved to this tool.
- You don't need to run the tool with **-u hdfs**, it works with a regular user.

Answer (score 2):

It states 'cannot write **parent** of file'. And the parent in your case is `/`. Take a look into the source:

```
private void verifyCanWriteParent(ArgumentParser parser, Path file) throws ArgumentParserException, IOException {
  Path parent = file.getParent();
  if (parent == null || !fs.exists(parent) || !fs.getFileStatus(parent).getPermission().getUserAction().implies(FsAction.WRITE)) {
    throw new ArgumentParserException("Cannot write parent of file: " + file, parser);
  }
}
```

In the message printed is `file`, in your case `hdfs:/hostname/dir`, so `file.getParent()` will be `/`.

Additionally you can try the permissions with `hadoop fs` command, for example you can try to create a zero length file in the path:

```
hadoop fs -touchz /test-file
```

Comment: I already saw that code and I thought about that. That's why I tried to put  that directory inside another one, like that: /dir/dir2. In that case, "dir" would be the parent of "dir2". I put 777 permissions on both directories and the error is the same. Should I put 777 (or write equivalent) permissions on / also? The checking does not seem to be recursive

Comment: I also tried the empty file thing because I thought that it might be expecting a file (and not a directory, which is weird), but the error is still the same

Comment: Did you check if you can write files with `hadoop fs` command? Do you use Kerberos?

Comment: Yes, I am able to write files with hadoop fs command. I'm not using Kerberos. I even tried to run everything with root but no result

Comment: Did you try to run it as `hdfs` user (sudo -u hdfs) and maybe giving the configuration xml by hand using `hadoop --config` argument?

Comment: I tried to run it as hdfs user exactly as in the examples, but no result. I can't find that config file on my station (that one: /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce1)

Comment: You can check what configuration you have in `/etc/hadoop`. For example you can have `/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/` which may contain config files like mapred-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml which I think could be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168313/discussion-between-cosmin-ioni-and-michal-lonski).